# User Authentication before Appcomponent is loaded in Angular2

Tags: angularjs, node.js, authentication, angular, auth0

I have a simple application which loads material design Ui through Appcomponent. I need to Authenticate the user before the app component is loaded.

The app component is as follows

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Router, RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,CanActivate} from 'angular2/router';
import {AuthHttp,AuthConfig, tokenNotExpired, AUTH_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2-jwt';


import {HomeComponent} from '../home/HomeComponent'
import {AboutComponent} from '../about/AboutComponent'
import {HeaderComponent} from './HeaderComponent'
import {LoginComponent} from '../login/LoginComponent'
import {AuthService} from '../../services/AuthService'
import {SidebarComponent} from './SidebarComponent'
import {DashboardComponent} from './DashboardComponent'
import {MDL} from './MaterialDesignLiteUpgradeElement';


@RouteConfig([
    {path: 'app/home', component: HomeComponent, as: 'Home'},
    {path: 'app/dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, as: 'Dashboard'},
    {path: 'app/about', component: AboutComponent, as: 'About'},    
    {path: 'app/login', component: LoginComponent, as: 'Login'},
    {path: 'app/*', redirectTo: ['Login']}   // this redirect is not working for some reason
])
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    /*template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>',*/
   template: `
    <body>
    <div class="demo-layout mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-drawer mdl-layout--fixed-header">
      <app-header mdl class="demo-header mdl-layout__header mdl-color--grey-100 mdl-color-text--grey-600"></app-    header>
      <app-sidebar class="demo-drawer mdl-layout__drawer mdl-color--blue-grey-900 mdl-color-text--blue-grey-50">
      </app-sidebar>
      <main class="mdl-layout__content mdl-color--grey-100">

          <router-outlet></router-outlet>

      </main>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.min.js"></script>
  </body>

    `, 
    /*styleUrls: ['../app/assets/styles.css'], */
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,SidebarComponent,HeaderComponent,MDL],
    providers: [AUTH_PROVIDERS,AuthService]
})

export class AppComponent { 

  constructor() {}

}
```

I have a login component which logs in the user as follows

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Router, RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router';
import {AuthHttp,AuthConfig, tokenNotExpired, AUTH_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2-jwt';

import {AuthService} from '../../services/AuthService'



@Component({
    selector: 'protected',
    template: '',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: [AUTH_PROVIDERS,AuthService]
})

export class LoginComponent { 

  constructor(private auth: AuthService) {
      this.auth.login();
  }
  login() {
     this.auth.login();
  }

  logout() {
    this.auth.logout();
  }

  static loggedIn() {
    return tokenNotExpired();
  }

}
```

The login component uses the AuthService

AuthService

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Router} from "angular2/router";

declare var Auth0Lock: any;

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

constructor(private router: Router) {}


  lock = new Auth0Lock('KEY','URL');

  login() {
   this.lock.show((error: string, profile: Object, id_token: string) => {
     if (error) {
       console.log(error);
       return false;
     }

     localStorage.setItem('profile', JSON.stringify(profile));
     localStorage.setItem('id_token', id_token);
     this.router.navigate(['Home']);

    });
 }

 logout() {
   localStorage.removeItem('profile');
   localStorage.removeItem('id_token');
 }
}
```

I tried annotating the AppComponent with @CanActivate  as follows 
 but that doesn't seems to be working as the AppComponent is loaded any how.

```
@CanActivate(() => LoginComponent.loggedIn())
export class AppComponent {      
}
```

Any ideas how to prevent the appComponent from loading without authnetication ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement your own `RouterOutlet` which overrides the `acitvate` method to check, if the person is allowed to navigate to that route.

```
import {Directive, DynamicComponentLoader, ElementRef} from "angular2/core";
import {AuthService} from '../../services/AuthService'
import {Router, RouterOutlet, ComponentInstruction} from "angular2/router";

@Directive({
    selector: 'auth-router-outlet'
})
export class AuthRouterOutlet extends RouterOutlet {
    private _protectedRoutes = {
        'app/home': true,
        'app/dashboard': true,
        'app/about': true
    };

    constructor(_elementRef: ElementRef, _loader: DynamicComponentLoader, private _router: Router, nameAttr: string, private _authService: AuthService) {
        super(_elementRef, _loader, _router, nameAttr);
    }

    activate(nextInstruction: ComponentInstruction): Promise<any> {
        if (this._protectedRoutes[nextInstruction.urlPath]) {
            if (!this._authService.loggedIn()) {
                this._router.navigate(['Login']);
            }
        }

        return super.activate(nextInstruction);
    }
}
```

In your `AppComponent` just replace the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` with `<auth-router-outlet></auth-router-outlet>`.

For the redirect in your `RouteConfig` use two asterisks like this:

```
@RouteConfig([
    {path: 'app/home', component: HomeComponent, as: 'Home'},
    {path: 'app/dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, as: 'Dashboard'},
    {path: 'app/about', component: AboutComponent, as: 'About'},    
    {path: 'app/login', component: LoginComponent, as: 'Login'},
    {path: 'app/**', redirectTo: ['Login']}   // two asterisks here
])
```

Comment: Property 'routeName' does not exist on type 'ComponentInstruction'.. Also what do I have in loggedIn() method ? the token ?

Comment: Which version of Angular are you using exactly?

Comment: the version is 2.0.0-beta.17

Comment: `loggedIn()` returns the status of your token, I guess? I'm using the exact same version and I've got no problems with the custom router outlet. Do you have your imports right?

Comment: Can you do a `console.log(nextInstruction)` before the `if` with the `_protectedRoutes` to check which members are available?

Comment: Hm, okay - I updated my answer accordingly! Please try it now!

Comment: Still getting the property error not sure why .. Property 'routeName' does not exist on type 'ComponentInstruction'

Comment: I think you're missing a change I made: `if (this._protectedRoutes[nextInstruction.urlPath]) {` - I replaced `routeName` with `urlPath` and modified the `_protectedRoutes` so it contains the route urls and not the names.

Comment: Thanks. seems to be working, but my base url is still not protected. I added this     export class AuthRouterOutlet extends RouterOutlet {
    private _protectedRoutes = {
        'app/': true,
        'app/home': true,
        'app/dashboard': true,
        'app/about': true
    };

Comment: For the redirect in your `RouteConfig` just use two asterisks - I updated the answer accordingly. :)

Comment: Any chance you can update this based on the new release candidate?  My custom router outlet is no longer working as they folded the RouterOutlet class into ROUTER_DIRECTIVES.

Comment: I sadly can't since I'm waiting for the final release until I touch anything new regarding Angular 2 :(